# How do I reposition a Form Validator error

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using the [jQuery form validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) which, for the most part, has been very successful (especially cool with conditional validation). However, I've got an error positioning issue I have not been able to solve.

I'm validating a series of checkboxes where I need the user to select at least one checkbox. This library has a function that handles this by adding a few attributes to the first checkbox input in the series. Here's my code:

```
          <label id="cb1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="Teacher/professor/clinician-educator" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" data-validation="checkbox_group" data-validation-qty="min1" data-validation-error-msg="Please select at least one checkbox" >
          <span id="firstLabel">Teacher/professor/clinician-educator facilitated the session</span></label>

        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="large-group" id="CheckboxGroup1_1">
          Large group (&gt; 50 individuals)</label>
```

I added a little extra markup (id="cb1" and the  so I could try to manipulate the error message's position and place it above the series of checkboxes rather than after the first checkbox (see screengrab below).

Here's the code after a validation error is generated:

```
<label id="cb1" class="has-error">
          <input name="CheckboxGroup1[]" value="Teacher/professor/clinician-educator" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" data-validation="checkbox_group" data-validation-qty="min1" data-validation-error-msg="Please select at least one checkbox" current-error="Please select at least one checkbox" class="error" style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" type="checkbox">

          <span id="firstLabel">Teacher/professor/clinician-educator facilitated the session</span>
```

Please select at least one checkbox
    
              
              Large group (> 50 individuals)

I've tried all manner of changing the margin-top for the injected code (`<span class="help-block form-error">Please select at least one checkbox</span>`) including the following:

```
#cb1.has-error span {
  margin-top: -45px;    
}
#cb1.has-error span#firstLabel {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Any suggestions? I reached out to the primary author but have not yet gotten a response and my client is getting itchy.

Thanks for all the help!

- Joe

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the note @ErcanPeker - I have tried changing it via display:block and I can put it above, but everything else comes with it, resulting in overlapping text.

Comment: sorry not horizontal but vertical; inline elements cannot have vertical margins. thats why,  margin-top: 20px; does not work.

Comment: I understood what you meant. I can declare it as a block element with CSS and reposition, but it's getting everything else in line now that is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define custom  message container for a certain input.

```
<div id="email-error-dialog"></div>
  <p>
 E-mail:
<input type="email" name="user-email" data-validation="email" 
     data-validation-error-msg="You did not enter a valid e-mail" 
     data-validation-error-msg-container="#email-error-dialog">
 </p>
```

source: http://www.formvalidator.net/#configuration_position

Comment: That's it! Bless you Ercan! I saw that in the docs, but obviously didn't understand how to use it or that it would apply in this case. Greatly appreciated!